# libgdx assetmanager texture loading

Tags: loading, libgdx, assets

here is my code:-

```
manager = new AssetManager();   

fps =new FPSLogger();

Resolution[] resolutions = {new Resolution(320, 480, ".320480"), new Resolution(480,    800, ".480800"),
new Resolution(480, 856, ".480854")};

 ResolutionFileResolver resolver = new ResolutionFileResolver(new InternalFileHandleResolver(), resolutions);

manager.setLoader(Texture.class, new TextureLoader(resolver));


 manager.load( "images/flash.png" , Texture.class);
 Texture.setAssetManager(manager);
tex =  manager.get("images/flash.png" ,Texture.class);


tex = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/a.png")); 
flsh = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/flash.png"));   
tex2 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/space.jpg")); 
ear = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/earth.png")); 
newgame=new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/shockwave.png"));
```

and the error that shows up is

```
 Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Asset not loaded: images/flash.png
at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.get(AssetManager.java:119)
at main.assets.loading(assets.java:53)
at main.game.create(game.java:43)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:132)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:112)
```

my image layout is

/main(project name)/assets/images/a.png

please help me rectify this error

Comment: Which platform are you in? Win, Android?

Comment: Windows is a bit problematic as it cannot reach the internal files as easily. The way it's built in my android+win project had linked folders which ar not supported by windows, so you had to access them by using "./assets/" in front of any file name.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/festevezga/wartricksproject/src/f156b447428cb7ea7a6fdb459a4b053b489f1332/WartricksProject/wartricks/src/com/wartricks/utils/PlatformUtils.java?at=master

Path being just the file name/folder in the internal storage.

Comment: my file path is    main(project name)/assets/images/a.png

Comment: @abhimanyu Try `AssetManager.finishLoading()` after you `load()` the assets.

Comment: i was wondering if i could load assets in render() because creating loading screen is my ultimate goal and i have read that asset manager do cause problem like slight lag after loading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use manager.finishloading() in between manager.load() and manager.get statements.